# Request Multiple WMS for Raster Calculations in Leaflet JS

Tags: leaflet, javascript, wms, leaflet-plugins

I need to display in leafletJS a Layer that is the difference of two rasters received from a regular WMS. With the help of [this repo](https://github.com/Zverik/leaflet-grayscale) I figured out how to manipulate the values of a raster tile in Leaflet using L.TileLayer.extend:

```js
import L from 'leaflet';

L.TileLayer.Manipulated = L.TileLayer.extend({

  initialize(url, options) {
    L.TileLayer.prototype.initialize.call(this, url, options);
    this.on('tileload', (e) =>  {
      if (!e.tile.getAttribute('manipulated-tile')) { // If tile is not manipulated yet
        this._manipulate(e.tile);
      }
    });
  },
  _manipulate(img) {
    const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    canvas.width = img.width;
    canvas.height = img.height;
    const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

    const imageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    const pix = imageData.data;
    for (var i = 0, n = pix.length; i < n; i += 4) {
      pix[i] = pix[i] * 0.8; // red
      pix[i + 1] = pix[i + 1] * 0.8; // green
      pix[i + 2] = pix[i + 2] * 0.6; // blue
    }
    ctx.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);
    img.setAttribute('manipulated-tile', true);
    img.src = canvas.toDataURL();
  },
});

L.tileLayer.manipulated = function (url, options) {
  return new L.TileLayer.Manipulated(url, options);
};
```

Usage:

```js
L.tileLayer.manipulated('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png');
```

Does anybody know a simple approach how I can get two geographically matching tiles of different layers and then calculate the difference between those? The calculations need to be done in the frontend.

Comment: Don't do this with WMS layers, they are pictures of the data and will probably have been anti-aliased and generalised - you need to use a WCS if you need actual data values

Answer (score 1):

I suggest leveraging [Leaflet.TileLayer.GL](https://gitlab.com/IvanSanchez/Leaflet.TileLayer.GL/), as it's capable of performing pixel manipulations on up to 8 `TileLayer`s at once, using the GPU in the browser's computer.

To get the difference between two `L.TileLayer.WMS` instances, it should go something like this:

```
var wms1 = L.tileLayer.wms(/* stuff */); // Will become uTexture0 in the shader
var wms2 = L.tileLayer.wms(/* stuff */); // Will become uTexture1 in the shader

var fragShader = `
void main void(){
    vec4 wms1texel = texture2D(uTexture0, vTextureCoords.st);  
    vec4 wms2texel = texture2D(uTexture1, vTextureCoords.st);  

    // The RGB component of the output shall be the difference
    // The Alpha component shall be 1 (fully opaque)
    gl_FragColor = vec4(wms2texel.rgb - wms1texel.rgb, 1.0);  
}
`;

L.tileLayer.gl({
    fragmentShader: fragShader,
    tileLayers: [wms1, wms2],
}).addTo(map);
```

WebGL shader programming might be different than what you're used to, so use resources like http://thebookofshaders.com/ to learn about how to code shaders.

In particular, the demo shader I wrote above will subtract the pixel values of `wms1` from the pixel values of `wms2`, and the result is then inherently clamped to the [0,1] range - meaning that if the values from `wms1` are larger than those of `wms2` the result will be black. You might want to use `abs` (`vec4(abs(wms2.rgb - wms1.rgb), 1.0)`) and/or bump up the result to look brighter (`vec4((wms2.rgb - wms1.rgb)*20.0, 1.0)`), or apply whatever other raster algebra manipulation you want.

Comment: Hei Ivan! The calculations work, however the layer I'm using is not georeferenced correctly.The actual pixels I want to see are very small at Lat 0 Lng 0.. However, if I use eg. OpenstreetMaps, the georeference works fine. And also if I add my layer as a regular L.Tilelayer.WMS the layer is shown correctly. Only if I want to use my layer inside a Tilelayer.gl the problem occurs. Do you know of this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this gist](https://gist.github.com/arashmad/7e873ed20e77a983754213eb4768f96b) which I've recently created.
Using this, you can get the URL of a tile image at a specific location and zoom level and then replace it's endpoint with another one to get second image at the same location.